# Criteria Hibernate Order By

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-order-by, criteria

I've got two classes with this relation:

```
Class Articulo:

private List<Poblacion> poblacionList;


Class Poblacion:

private String nombre;
```

I want to do a query and order by the result by the nombre property:

> Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Articulo.class);

I mean i want to do something like...

> criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("poblacionList.nombre"));

But this didn't work properly so can i do any trick to do this order?

Sorry for my english and thanks in advice

Comment: So assuming you have one entity of `Articulo` and two entities of `Poblacion` which are part of the list in `Articulo`. What do you expect in the result? How should a single `Articulo` entity be sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have a reference to the Poblacion entity.

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Articulo.class, "articulo")
                             .createAlias("articulo.poblacionList", "poblacion");

//... your projections or something else

criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("poblacion.nombre")); //using the alias.
```